# `ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES` when play video in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

- Step to reduce:

Use chrome to visit
http://img.c.huaweistatic.com/content/dam/huawei-cbg-site/other/jp/mkt/homepage/section6/home-s6-nova-video.mp4

Then the video begins to play, open Chrome Dev Tool, on the network page, I recognise many requests to this video, and some of them are canceled.

Open the chrome://net-internals/#events to see what happened, I see this error:

```
t=4299 [st=838]    HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_BODY  [dt=1]
t=4300 [st=839]    HTTP_CACHE_WRITE_DATA  [dt=1]
t=4301 [st=840]    URL_REQUEST_JOB_FILTERED_BYTES_READ
               --> byte_count = 3472
t=4301 [st=840]    CANCELLED
               --> net_error = -12 (ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES)
t=4301 [st=840] -REQUEST_ALIVE
```

How the `net_error = -12 (ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES)` happened?

Comment: Definitely looks like a bug in Chrome. There's no need for all those hundreds and thousands of requests when playing sequentially from the start. Care to submit a bug report on https://crbug.com ?

Comment: Yes, may be a very old bug in Chrome, see:  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=157993